# How to prevent Visual Studio Community 2022 from opening each file in a separate instance?

Tags: visual-studio-2022, single-instance

I'm using Windows 11 Pro 22H2 OS build: 22621.1485 and Visual Studio Community 2022.

Imagine please, I have 3 PHP files in my workplace folder. If I double click on each PHP file on Windows Explorer (File Manager) Visual Studio Community 2022 opens each file in a separate instance.

[image: image showing three instances of visual studio - one for each file]

I want to Visual Studio Community 2022 opens each file in a single instance.

I go to "Tools" -> "Options" -> "Environment" -> "Tabs and Windows" and unchecked the "Open documents in preview tab" option but did not work. I couldn't see any other settings to change behaviour of tabs or windows.

Anyone can help me about this?

Thanks in advance.

Berksoy

Comment: That is normal, you can't change the way Explorer works.  Favor File > Open > File or the Show All Files toolbar button in the Solution Explorer pane.

Comment: Hey if you launch the files from the explorer then they will be opened in three separate windows because that is what explorer does. Visual Studio will open the three files in three separate windows. I know you were expecting visual studio to behave like Chrome where each file is opened as a tab in the same window but Visual Studio does not know if the files belong to the same project so it will open them separately.

Comment: @dong-li thanks for your comment. I get it but Visual Studio Code opens them in a single instance. Why Visual Studio Community can't do what Visual Studio Code can?